# Функция возвращает некорректное значение C++

Tags: c++

Здравствуйте,подскажите, пожалуйста.

Я не могу найти ошибку в функции `DataType getCursor()`, она возвращает неправильное значение. Подскажите, пожалуйста,что я не так делаю?

После дебаггинга понял , что переменная `cursor` имеет правильное значение, а сам `dataItems[cursor];` возвращает мусор.
И сама сумма также неверна.

**listADT.h**

```
const int defMaxListSize = 10;
typedef int DataType;

class ListADT
{
private:
    //Data members
    int maxSize=11;
    int size=10;
    int cursor=0;

    DataType *dataItems=NULL;
public:
    //Constructor
    ListADT(int maxNumber = defMaxListSize);

    //Destructor
    ~ListADT();

    //List manipulation operations
    void insert(const DataType &newDataItem);   //Insert after cursor
    void remove();                              //Remove Data item
    //void replace(const DataType &newDataItem);    //Replace data item


    //List status operations 
    bool isEmpty()const;                        //List is empty
    bool isFull() const;                        //List is full

    //List iteration operations
    void gotoBeginning() ;  //Go to beginning
    void gotoEnd();         //Go to end
    bool gotoNext();        //Go to next data item
    bool gotoPrior();       //Go to prior data item
    DataType getCursor();   //Return data item

    //Output the list structure -used in testinf/debugging
    //void showStructure()const;
};
```

**listADT.cpp**

```
#include "ListADT.h"

ListADT::ListADT(int maxNumber)
{
    cursor = 0;
    dataItems = new DataType[maxNumber];
    //dataItems = { 0 };
}

ListADT::~ListADT()
{
    delete [] dataItems;
}

void ListADT::insert(const DataType & newDataItem)
{
    if (size + 1 <= maxSize) 
    {
        dataItems[cursor] = newDataItem;
        cursor++;
    }

}

void ListADT::remove()
{
    if (size - 1 >= 0)
        cursor--;
}

bool ListADT::isEmpty() const
{
    if (size <= 0)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

bool ListADT::isFull() const
{
    if (size == defMaxListSize)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

void ListADT::gotoBeginning()
{
    cursor = 0;
}

void ListADT::gotoEnd()
{
    cursor = size;
}

bool ListADT::gotoNext()
{
    if (cursor < size)
    {
        cursor++;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

bool ListADT::gotoPrior()
{
    if (!isEmpty() && cursor != 1)
    {
        cursor--;
        return true;
    }
    else return false;
}

DataType ListADT::getCursor()
{
    if (!isEmpty())
    {
        std::cout << "C: " << cursor << std::endl; //правильный результат
        return dataItems[cursor]; // возвращает мусор
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Empty list" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

**source.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "ListADT.h"

void main()
{
    ListADT samples;
    int newSample=0;
    int total = 0;

    //Read in a set of samples from the keyboard.
    std::cout << "Enter list of samples (end with eof): ";
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        std::cin >> newSample;
        samples.insert(newSample);
    }
    //Sum the samples and output the result.

        if (!samples.isEmpty())
        {
            samples.gotoBeginning();

            do {
                std::cout << "CUR " << samples.getCursor() << std::endl;
                total += samples.getCursor();
            }
            while (samples.gotoNext());
        }
        std::cout << "Sum is " << total << std::endl;
        system("pause");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

в цикле когда cursor 9, проверяется gotonext() меньше ли 10 - да, тут же увеличиваем на 1 в теле функции теперь cursor=10 (в массиве всего 10 - от 0 до 9), идем в тело цикла чтобы вывести еще раз, и получаем dataItems[10] т.е. 11 элемент а там мусор.

в gotonext можно if(cursor < size-1)